# How to query non-index field on Big Object?

Tags: soql, big-object, async-soql

I'm learning Big Object on trailhead and I have completed deploy the big object to my org.

But I have a question is that: how can I query non-index field by SOQL? I know that only index fields can be used in filter and returned, how can I get the value of those non-index fields? When I include non-index field in SOQL, it said:
"No such column 'Level_Achieved__c' on entity 'Customer_Interaction__b' ".

If I can't get the value of those fields, how can I reuse those records in big objects in the future?

Below is the SOQL I Use:

```
SELECT Account__c,CreatedById, Level_Achieved__c FROM Customer_Interaction__b
```

[image: SOQL Error Message]

[image: My Big Object Data Model]

Comment: Can you check FLS of those fields ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks, I found I forget edit the FLS for those fields, now I can query those fields in SOQL.

Comment: Added as an answer to help others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is your system admin profiles do not have the field level security as read for those fields .

Check your system administrator profile and Mark these fields with read permission at least to use in soql .